# Jquery ui autocomplete php retrieve names

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jquery UI autocomplete widget to retrieve names out of a mysql table in a php file (nameSearch.php)

It's not retrieving the results properly. Is there anything wrong with the Jquery I have here? Should it return results to the input with id 'tags'?

I'm getting  the '$_GET['term']' variable in the php file  which I understand is sent from the autocomplete request to the php file?

This is the Jquery code I have:

```
<script>
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "nameSearch.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
</script>
```

php

```
    <?php

    $namePart=$_GET['term'];
    $names = array();

// Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','filmdatabase'); 
        // Query Database
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM actor WHERE name like    '%".$namePart."%'");
        $arr = '';

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    array_push($names,$row['name']);
                }

       echo json_encode($names);
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code looks just fine. What is the php returning?

Comment: Can you please provide your `php` code?

Comment: Well unless I add in ?term=(something) at the end of the url for that php file, it comes up with:

Notice: Undefined index: term in C:\webserver\webroot\nameSearch.php on line 3 and then a whole bunch of names from the database

Comment: did you look into firebug what you really get from you php after typing something into your autocomplete box? if the notice still appears then your autocomplete won't lode because the returned result is not a json (because it contains the notice) and it doesn't do anything... already had this problem

Comment: @user1060187 instead of `echo` can you please use `print(json_encode($names))` ?

Comment: @ITroubs I have manually set the browswer url to http://localhost/nameSearch.php?term=a This returns a valid JSON of ["Brad Pitt","Colin Farrell","Jake Gyllenhaal ","Ralph Fiennes","Jack Nicholson","Dustin Hoffman","Denzel Washington","Aaron Eckhart"]

Comment: @OscarJara I tried printing but still nothing

Comment: @user1060187 that is not what I asked for and not what autocomplete does! you have to check what you get back from the php in firebug or in another dev tool like dragonfly in opera or the dev tool of chrome!

Comment: @OscarJara The .php is expecting a $_GET['term'] variable from the jquery source request. I could do an !empty on the variable to get rid of that error but the page would only be called anyway if someone types something into the input field.

Comment: @Itroubs Which page? nameSearch.php or where my input field is located?

Comment: @ITroubs I used firebug and cleared the current buffer, typed into the input box and no response came back

Comment: so basically nothing appeared there?

Comment: did you wrap your autocomplete in a $(document).ready(function(){....});?

Comment: @ITroubs that solved it.. Feel like a fool! Props to you :)

Comment: yeah that is often overlooked and even more often underestimated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `$(document).ready(function(){....});?` as a wrapper solved the Problem